# Mainframe : JCL DISP parameters

Tags: mainframe

I would like to know the difference between KEEP and UNCATLG.
As per my knowledge both will remove the catalog entry for the datasets.

Thanks and Regards,Manasi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe so. `KEEP` will not remove the entry from the catalog *if it was already there*. `UNCATLG` will remove it no matter what.

I think that, if you want to keep the data set, you have three options:

- `CATLG` will give you a catalog entry regardless of whether one existed before.
- `UNCATLG` will remove the catalog entry regardless of whether one existed before.
- `KEEP` will not change the catalog entry.

All those options keep the data set itself.

If you're talking specifically about SMS-managed or VSAM data sets, `KEEP` is implied and `UNCATLG` is ignored.

Comment: If we are using KEEP as a DISP parameter then next time when we want to access that dataset we have to specify VOL SER no for the same. If the catalog entry is present then we can access the datasets directly by giving the names,rite?

Comment: @Manasi Have a look at [Normal Disposition sub-parameter](http://publibfp.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr/BOOKS/IEA2B660/12.19.2.2?SHELF=&DT=20050713232151&CASE=). And, yes if you use KEEP on a new non SMS managed dataset, you need the VOL SER to access it again.

Comment: As per the link I think in both the cases catalog entry will be removed.And the dataset will be present in volume without catalog entry which we will access by providing volume serial number.Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Manasi. The answer supplied by pasdiablo is correct. If the dataset already exists, KEEP will not change the catalog entry: If it is cataloged it stays cataloged; if not cataloged, then it remains uncataloged. In an SMS managed environment: KEEP implies CATALOG for a new dataset (so new datasets are always cataloged and remain so).